# ansible shell/command module not executing script at remote machine

Tags: shell, tomcat, ansible

While trying to run startup.sh script for Tomcat-8, I am getting below error. Playbook is executing successfully with STDOUT- "Tomcat started" but it is not reflecting in the remote machine.
The error is there for both modules - command and shell

```
- name: Download Tomcat version 8
  get_url: 
  url: http://mirrors.wuchna.com/apachemirror/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.35/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.35.tar.gz 
  dest: /tmp/apache-tomcat-8.5.35.tar.gz

- name: Untar Tomcat to /opt
  shell: tar -zxvf apache-tomcat-8.5.35.tar.gz -C /opt
  args:
    chdir: /tmp/
    warn: False

- name: Change permissions of Tomcat folder
  file:
    path: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.35
    mode: 0777
    recurse: yes

- name: Set Catalina Home
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
    regexp: '^#?\s*export CATALINA_HOME=(.*)$'
    line: 'export CATALINA_HOME=/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.35'
    state: present

- name: execute source
  shell: source maven.sh
  args:
    chdir: /etc/profile.d/
    executable: /bin/sh

- name: start catalina
  become: true
  command: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.35/bin/startup.sh &>> /var/log/log.txt
```

Comment: Use -vv or -vvv to enable verbose output when you run your plays.  That should give you a better idea of what is going wrong.

Comment: `source` is a bash shell built-in try `executable: /bin/bash`

Comment: Hi Sebthebert, Tried /bin/bash also, not working.

Answer (score 0):

Tried running your tasks in a playbook on Centos7 and it executes successfully with Tomcat up and healthy. (Had to install maven first)
I might need more info to debug this.

- Q: Are you planning to run tomcat as root user? (if you are.. you
  shouldn't)
- Q: What is the OS on remote?
- Q: Have you installed JRE or
  JDK properly ?

Have a look at this example: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/tree/master/tomcat-standalone

Comment: Yes Anant, Java is installed properly on remote machine. This startup script is working fine when running manually, only from ansible its not working

Comment: Hey Swati, Can you post the logs from /var/log/log.txt ?

Comment: Hi Anant, below is the content of log file: Tomcat started.
Tomcat started.
Tomcat started.
Tomcat started.
Tomcat started.
Tomcat started.
Tomcat started.
Tomcat started.
Tomcat started.
Tomcat started.
Tomcat started.
Tomcat started.

Comment: Hi Anant, Remote machine has  RHEL Server release 6.9 (Santiago) version.